# How to reattach eventListeners?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Function `prepareMapEventListener()` adds 256 EventListeners (`el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords) });`)

After I hange code with outerHTML in `document.getElementById(XxY).outerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` I have to redo adding EventListener for that element, which I tried to accomplish with:

```
// refresh clicable map after it's edited
function refreshMapEventListener() {
    var el = document.getElementById(position);
    el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', position) });
}
```

but it does half of its job: it updates Listeners but only for last element clicked - If I click 10 elements and than want to alter 5th of them - 10th element will be changed.

So I tried reapplying Listeners to every element with deleting and replacing `refreshMapEventListener();` with `prepareMapEventListener()`in:

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(XxY).outerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
            refreshMapEventListener();
            hideloading();
        }
    }
```

and it works! But each try doubles output - so after 2 click I have 3 AJAX calls, after 3 clicks I have 6, than 12.

How to solve that?

## Live example (make sure to watch console/firebug):

http://xn--wiadomesny-37b.pl/stackoverflow/

## Full code below:

```
// prepare clicable map
function prepareMapEventListener() {
    for (x = 1; x <= 16; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= 16; y++) {
        (function prepareClickableMap() {
            var cords = x + "x" + y;
            var el = document.getElementById(cords);
            el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', cords) });
        })();
    }
    }
}

// selection mode
var s;
function selectionMade(e) {
    selection = e.currentTarget.id.split("_"); 
    s = selection[1];
}

// send edited map info to DB
var position;
function B_modeWindow (id,XxY) {  
    if (s !== undefined) {    
        loading();
    
        var xmlhttp;
        position = XxY;
    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    
        var xy = position.split("x"); 
    
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(XxY).outerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                prepareMapEventListener();
                hideloading();
            }
        }
    
        xmlhttp.open("GET","processMapEdit.php?id="+id+"&x="+xy[0]+"&y="+xy[1]+"&s="+s,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to modify `element.outerHTML`?

Comment: When `element.outerHTML` is chanegd I need to recall `el.addEventListener("click", function (e) { B_modeWindow('1', position) })` on it

Comment: I mean, is there any other way to modify your page, other than using `outerHTML`? It's fast for coding, but not quite "elegant" in some cases, like now.

Comment: I dont know, learning JS really. What I want to do is: when I click on something I get string returned by AJAX and want to replace DIV's class I clicked with that string.

Comment: If you just want to replace element's class, setting `element.className="tileBox pos_28"` is quite enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment (and your live example) we learnt that all you want is just a new `class` for HTML element. That's much easier...

Change your

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(XxY).outerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                prepareMapEventListener();
                hideloading();
            }
        }
```

to

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById(XxY).className=xmlhttp.responseText;
                hideloading(); //I don't know what this is, so I leave it here
            }
        }
```

**And** modify your `processMapEdit.php` to return only the desired class name instead of a whole `DIV` element.

Also, there might be some browser that doesn't work well when `XMLHttpRequest` fetched plain text instead of valid XML text, so you may want to add

```
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/plain")
```

before `send()`.